# Application not showing up in google play store

Tags: google-play, search-engine, publish, android

I have published an application in the google play store and this is now 'in prod'.

When I search for this in google play via either my phone or laptop, the application doesn't show up until very low in the app listings (number 50 to 100 of the search results) even though I use the exact name of the app in the search and many of the search results above it are unrelated and definitely less relevant to the search keywords.

Is there something simple in the naming convention or description in the play store that will help solve this problem?

Comment: metion you package name

Comment: try to search in this way https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.testapp&hl=en-- com.example.testapp is you package name once app is succesfuly upload it will directly display like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application has to be indexed that greater the no of installation the higher the index . The best way will be try to make people install the application it will increase the indexing of you app..